# java.lang.Exception:java.lang.Exception:HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
・・・omission・・・`

    HttpsURLConnection huc=null;
    StringBuffer responsebuff=null;
    URL posturl=null;
    PrintWriter writer=null;
    BufferedReader br=null;
    DOMParser parser=null;
    NodeList nl=null;
    Element e=null;
    NodeList lastEventList=null;
    Element lastEventElement=null;
    Response response = new Response();
    try{
        responsebuff = new StringBuffer();
        posturl = new URL(request.getDomain());
        huc = (HttpsURLConnection)posturl.openConnection();
```

I have confirmed that it works normally without error (On live server).
But after I modified some sources of different logic, and restarted the TOMCAT, 
it throws ClassCastException at the last row of the source.
The detail of error:

```
java.lang.Exception:java.lang.Exception:java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionOldImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

java version : 1.6.0_23

There isn't any relations between the modified part and the throwing error part.
However, the error is resolved when I restart the TOMCAT. 
Is there anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Your code has casted an Object to a subclass which is not related to it.

Comment: "after I modified some sources of different logic": 
It's impossible to help you properly when you only provide vague details like that. Would you accept that from a customer in a problem report?